# Получить объект класс из потока в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, объекты

Сервер приложения IBM WebSphere, соответственно, запущен на IBM JVM.
Приложение работает в несколько потоков, как WebContainer, так и фоновые процессы.
В отдельным потоке получаю все потоки, которые запущены в данной JVM, таким образом:

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
for(Thread t: threadSet){
   ...
}
```

Можно ли каким-то образом получить список всех объектов, например класса java.sql.Connection, или его наследников, и уже от их имени выполнить какой-то запрос к БД.

Например, несколько потоков имею свои подключения к БД и мне надо знать какой SQL_ID используется каждым потоком.

Возможно это реализовать? Может есть другой способ решения данной задачи?

Comment: Звучит так, будто вы пытаетесь решить какую-то задачу в корне неправильно. Какая конечная цель?

Comment: Конечная цель, получить список соединений к БД для каждого моего потока. После чего необходимо узнать SID (конечно Oracle SID, а не SQL_ID - опечатка в первом сообщении).

Comment: Еще одна мысль была, это сделать свой MyConnection implements Connection и когда происходит создание соединения помещать нужную информацию в карту, потом при необходимости ее читать.

Comment: А каким образом потоки "владеют" этими соединениями? Они обернуты в `ThreadLocal`? Все-таки в общем случае экземпляры классов и потоки, которые вызывают на них методы ортогональны друг другу и не состоят в отношении *has-a*.

Comment: Задача все усложняется и усложняется. В WebSphere есть ConnectionPool, соединения естественно не ThreadLocal. Сам java thread получает лишь обертку и выполняет запрос через него. О настоящем соединении знает только WebSphere.

Comment: Это как раз совершенно естественно. То есть теперь вы хотите подергать все соединения из пула?

Comment: Ну получается, что да. Нужно получить соединение, узнать его SID на сервере и связать с тредом на сервере приложений.

Comment: Для чего это нужно - например, есть 16 серверов в кластере, каждый держит по 10 соединений. В один момент времени, в топ-5 запросов вылезает очень активный запрос и отрывается на много вперед от остальных. Необходимо понять, какая ветка в java-коде вызвала этот запрос, снять ThreadDump и тому подобное. Дальше анализировать уже участок этого кода, оптимизировать работу

Comment: Все, понятно. Видел такое решение: дописывать в каждый запрос комментарий с какими-то метаданными из Java (уникальный ключ, имя  потока, `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()` или что угодно еще)  и использовать это для отладки.

Comment: Это не очень подходящий вариант, потому что будет меняться SQL_ID, что не лучшим образом скажется на производительности выполнения запроса